# How to query for rows that do not contain a value in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, key-value, nosql

I have a table levelToGames with hash key "level" (int) corresponding to the level of a game and attributes "gameId" for the game id.
I want to retrieve the first gameId that has the "given" level (let's call it myLevel) and also this row/game cannot have that player already in the game.
My solution is the table above with different attributes for row corresponding to each player ID. So, that way I can do a query like `level = myLevel AND attribute_not_exists(myPlayerID)`. However, this seems very hacky and I am not sure of what is the limit of attributes per table.

I would appreciate some input or advice on this.
Thanks!

P.S. An option I had in mind was using contains but it seems like I am not allowed to use NOT and contains together in one condition

Comment: What is the hash/range of your table?  Do you have an LSIs or GSIs?

Comment: hash key = level (int),
no range key, no LSIs or GSIs

Comment: If level is the hash key then this question needs to be clarified because by definition the level would be unique for each record.  Spell out the requirements better because it sounds like a range key or a GSI is likely needed to meet your requirements.

Comment: a range key is needed, but my question is what type of range key and which range key could help solve this problem.